# Better way to write these SQL statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to read data for reporting purpose. Currently, I populate a table using another table's calculated data, and read data for reporting from the populated table. My current logic is too delete the old data, and insert the new data, all within a transaction.

**UPDATE**

Requirements

1) The logic below is to run once every second. Please note that other processes also udpates tableB with the same refresh rate.

2) TableB is used for reporting purpose. TableA and TableB resides in different databases.

3) TableB contains around 10 millions rows, around 4 millions rows will be updated once every second by the code below. Other processes also update the other part of data (6 = 10-4 millions) in tableB at the same refresh rate.

My concern is that:

1) three statements use similar sum, and where clauses, which might be improved.

2) There are about 1-2 millions row in tablea to update to tableB. Using an explicit temporary table might slow down.

3) Using transaction might slow down, but it seems the only way.

4) Update the data might be a better option than delete and insert (which one should I choose?)

I want to find a better performant way (including table redesign etc.). Below is the current way:

pseudocode below:

```
start/begin transaction here    

DELETE from tableb data that I want to insert below, e.g. delete data where Code = 'code'


INSERT INTO tableb(Code, Total)
SELECT sum(a.Code, price)
FROM tablea a
GROUP BY a.Code;

IINSERT INTO tableb(Code, Total)
SELECT sum(a.Code price)   -- use price
FROM tablea a
WHERE a.meanPrice IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a.Code;

INSERT INTO tableb(Code, Total)
SELECT sum(a.Code, meanPrice )   -- use meanPrice
FROM tablea a
WHERE a.meanPrice IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a.Code;


Commit transaction here
```

It is for MySQL, but ideally it should be generic.

Any idea?

Comment: It is for MySQL, but ideally it should be generic.

Comment: So what's wrong with the ones you have that you want them improved? (And what are you actually trying to accomplish?)

Comment: @X-Zero The name price2 is for demo only. I will change it for the example.

Comment: @millimoose two statement retrieve the same data, but select different one, there might be room for performance improvement.

Comment: @Pingpong The obvious improvement that would knock at least a linear factor off is replacing this with a stored procedure that only walks `tablea` once.

Comment: @millimoose what do you mean by replacing this with stored procedure that only walks tables once? Could you elaborate it?

Comment: A `MERGE` in SQL Server can perform an "upsert".  I don't know about equivalents in the other DBs.

Comment: How many rows will be in `tableb` after the inserts?

Comment: Also, how often are you planning on updating this?  1 - 2 million rows is piddling change in most systems, especially on anything that's dedicated database hardware.  You may not have an actual performance problem.

Comment: @biziclop there will be about 10 millions rows in the destination table.

Comment: @X-Zero It update 1 every second.

Comment: @Leandro Thank you for changing tag. If you provide a good answer, I will mark it. Otherwise, I cannot. It is that simple.

Comment: So you want to delete and re-insert 10 million rows into `tableb` each second? Maybe you should use a view instead.

Comment: @bizciop It is around 4 millions to update, but the table contains around 10 millions. Do you mean replace the tableB with view instead? What is the reason, if you don't mind explain a bit. Thanks!

Comment: Despite the fact that dedicated database hardware probably _can_ pull this off (given appropriate indicies), you probably don't want to.  What is your end goal - why do you need to summary table in the first place?

Comment: @X-Zero It is for reporting purpose, ie. tableb is used for reporting. Could you elaborate on your previous post?

Comment: And you need to report once a second?  That kind of refresh rate screams transactional database.  If the summary data takes a good amount of time, do nightly extracts or something.  If you need 'current' data, just get the summaries on demand (using @Gordon's statement), when a user asks for them.

Comment: @Pingpong How do you expect to improve the performance characteristics of code if you can't even understand its performance characteristics? Basically, you're walking *three* times over all the rows of a table. (Unless you have them indexed on the nullness of `price` and `meanPrice`, and this condition is highly selective.) The obvious improvement is to only walk all these rows *once* instead of three times, which is what Gordon's answer seems to do. This however only takes you from linear complexity to better linear complexity.

Comment: @X-Zero I agree with your statement regarding how to collect data for different refresh rate.

Comment: @Pingpong The next improvement after that is going from linear complexity to constant (-ish) complexity, where things get tricky. You'd want to update the sums incrementally by doing something like looking at the previous sum, then adding all the prices since that sum was determined. (And substracting the ones that got deleted.) This would probably require a few changes to your database, like marking in `tableb` when the record was made so you know which prices to add. (And even more changes if you need to be able to substract.) An easier option is just running the query less often.

Comment: @millimoose I will consider your previous two posts. Perhaps, tableB has been re-designed so that the amount of data that needs change can be reduced.

Comment: @Pingpong Unless you have only very few records in `tableA` for every code, your problem lies in how much data you have to read. (I.e. all of it.) If you manage to redesign your app so the sums are determined incrementally as I described in the latter comment, you will however also reduce the amount of records in `tableB` that have to be written, so it's a win-win. Unless what you mean by the redesign is that you won't need to update the summary data for all the codes every time, which will bring the same kind of improvement for both reads and writes.

Comment: @millimoose I think fundamental improvement could be done on the architecture level and table design level first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query does your `INSERT` task in 1 step, but ... kids, don't do this at home without actually measuring actual performance:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/381e2/9

```
INSERT INTO tableb(Total)
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN t.v = 1
    THEN SUM( price )

    WHEN t.v = 2
    THEN SUM(
           CASE
           WHEN meanPrice IS NOT NULL THEN price
           ELSE 0
           END
         )

    WHEN t.v = 3
    THEN SUM( meanPrice )
  END AS Total

FROM tablea

INNER JOIN
  ( SELECT 1 AS v UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS v UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS v
  ) AS t

GROUP BY tablea.Code, t.v;
```

Comment: Your code looks very good to me given that the design of the tables. Might I try it out and let you know afterwards? Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually need to update values in the table?  They are not tagged with any id or names to identify them.

The following SELECT statement returns the data you want:

```
SELECT code,
       sum(price),
       sum(case when a.meanPrice is not null then price else 0 end),
       sum(case when a.meanPrice is not null then meanprice else 0 end)
FROM tablea a
GROUP BY a.Code;
```

If you needed to insert this into a temp table, you can unpivot the data.  However, that format does not make sense to me.  Can you explain why you are using a table with one numeric column in this way?

Comment: You could write the third SUM as `COALESCE( SUM( a.meanPrice ), 0 )`.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, You seem to suggest not to insert into tableb. Do I misunderstand that. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: @Pingpong . . . what are you using the results for?  You can calculate the values at the code level.  If you only need the values for output purposes, then SELECT is fine.  I can't see how your one-column table would be used, since you don't know which code is attached to which value, and whether the value is done by calculation 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Sorry for the confusion. I updated the code. The result is for reporting purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Point 3 is false.

Solution 1: Create an store procedure.

Solution 2: Create a trigger on the impacted tables.

Solution 3: Don't ask for a sum every time, do the sum the first time and then save the number on another table. On every modification of this table, do the sum over your new table, I wont be 1 millions records, only one per table.

Pivot tables!

Comment: Your point about point 3 is false, transactions consume (potentially a lot of) resources.  SP are not likely to provide noticeable gains.  Triggers may cause interesting problems, and we don't have enough here to know if that would help any.  The OP is attempting to 'save off' the summary to his destination table already - triggering to update can cause interesting data-race issues, besides any update inconsistencies.

Comment: @Leandro Thank you for your advice. But trigger might not be suitable for the scenario.

Comment: I think the best is change the logic to the solution 3, like if you want a "sql dependency" made ownself